# Finding the negative sum of a contiguous sublist using java 8

Tags: performance, list, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

I am trying to optimize the following code:

```
private final static class SubarrayProcessorNegativeSumStrategy 
    implements SubarrayProcessorStrategy {
    @Override public Integer apply(Integer[] array) {
        final List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(array);
        return (int) IntStream.range(0, numbers.size())
            .map(index -> findNegativeSums(numbers, index)).sum();
    } 
    private Integer findNegativeSums(final List<Integer> numbers, 
                                     final Integer startIndex) {
    final Integer numbersSize = numbers.size();
    if (startIndex < numbersSize) {
        return (int) IntStream.range(startIndex, numbers.size())
        .map(newIndex -> numbers.subList(startIndex, newIndex + 1)
        .stream().mapToInt(x -> x).sum())
        .filter(sum -> sum < 0).count();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid iterating from `startIndex` to `newIndex + 1` for every element of the original List

`numbers.subList(startIndex, newIndex + 1).stream().mapToInt(x -> x).sum()`

Do you have any suggestion how can I achieve this ? or if you could provide with any improvements to obtain the same result ?

Thank you

Regards,

Comment: Can you provide us with a little test code to understand, how your code should work?
And what is your primary goal of optimization: runtime or memory footprint?

Comment: Hi @cyberbrain, for example A=[1, -2, 4, -5, 1] should output 9. I am trying to optimize the memory. Thanks

Comment: @eduardo.leon Please update your question including this little example

Comment: So 9 because 9 of the possible sublists have negative sums ([1, -2], [1, -2, 4, -5], [1, -2, 4, -5, 1], [-2], [-2, 4, -5], [-2, 4, -5, 1], [4, -5], [-5] and [ -5, 1]). Have I got it?

Comment: My taste would be for `mapToInt(Integer::intValue)`. Obviously `mapToInt(x -> x)` works too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to implement it via the `Stream` API, there is no need to go through the `List` API detour. Further, the «sum of the element counts» is the total count of all elements, if you perform a single `flatMap` stream operation:

```
private final static class SubarrayProcessorNegativeSumStrategy
    implements SubarrayProcessorStrategy {
    @Override public Integer apply(Integer[] array) {
        return (int)IntStream.rangeClosed(0, array.length)
            .flatMap(index -> IntStream.range(0, index)
                .map(newIndex -> Arrays.stream(array,newIndex,index).mapToInt(x->x).sum())
                .filter(sum -> sum < 0))
            .count();
    }
}
```

This still has the same time complexity of the nested iterations. If you want to optimize the execution time, a stateful operation suits the task much better, which isn’t a good use case for the `Stream` API. Using ordinary loops is straight-forward:

```
private final static class SubarrayProcessorNegativeSumStrategy 
    implements SubarrayProcessorStrategy {
    @Override public Integer apply(Integer[] array) {
        int count=0;
        for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
            for(int newIndex = index, currSum = 0; newIndex < array.length; newIndex++) {
                currSum += array[newIndex];
                if(currSum < 0) count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Really the nested for blocks are waaaay much better, IMHO

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner: they turn the `O(n³)` time complexity to `O(n²)`…

Comment: this puts my answer to shame - which I'm happy about. plus one.

Answer (score 2):

I took a slightly different approach, in first finding all the indexes that you care about. For example in an array `[5,6,7]`, would produce indexes:

```
 3, 2, 1
 3, 2
 3
 2, 1
 2
 1
```

And then just collect the value from these indexes into a `sum`.

```
 private static long applyMine(int[] array) {
    return IntStream.range(0, array.length)
            .flatMap(i -> IntStream.iterate(i, x -> x + 1)
                    .takeWhile(x -> x != array.length)
                    .map(m -> IntStream.iterate(array.length - i, x -> x - 1)
                            .takeWhile(x -> x >= array.length - m)
                            .map(x -> array[x - 1])
                            .sum())
                    .filter(s -> s < 0))
            .count();
}
```

Comment: You know, `takeWhile` is Java 9… And the combination of `iterate(seed, next)` and `takeWhile(predicate)` can be written as `iterate(seed, predicate, next)`, still, it’s not better than `IntStream.range` in the current context.

Comment: @Holger I keep forgetting that jdk-9 is the default I have :( totally agree on the comments you have. I lost so much time putting this(could not let it alone) that at the end I stopped thinking clear.